# Boolean in python iterator

Tags: python, iterator, boolean

I am running a very lengthy script and this would work:

```py
    # sample line 
    line =  '....,,,,.,..,.,.,.4GCCG.,..,,,.,.,,.2TG'

    # search for numbers in line
    numbers = re.search(["[0-9]", line)

    if numbers is not None:
       numbers = re.finditer("[0-9]", line)
       some_process_on_each(numbers)
```

But searching twice for numbers in each line is not efficient.

Is there a way to compare the callable_iterator obtained from `re.finditer("[0-9]", line)` to something to get a boolean (perhaps I can know the space on memory?) so I can do something like:

```py
    # sample line 
    line =  '....,,,,.,..,.,.,.4GCCG.,..,,,.,.,,.2TG'

    # search for numbers in line
    numbers = re.finditer(["[0-9]", line)

    if numbers is ??:
        some_process_on_each(numbers)
```

Thank you

Comment: Why not just try iterating? `for n in re.finditer(...)`?

Comment: @pault ups... Right... Why I was so stubborn and checking it...bah, thank you!

Comment: also if you're just searching for single numbers, there's no need for regex - you can use `str.isdigit` for example: `for n in filter(str.isdigit, line):`

Comment: @pault right. And actually for numbers, disregarding the number of digits I better use '-\d+'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try iterating.

```
import re
line =  '....,,,,.,..,.,.,.4GCCG.,..,,,.,.,,.2TG'
for n in re.finditer("[0-9]", line):
    print(line[slice(*n.span())])
#4
#2
```

If there are no numbers, then there is nothing to iterate over.